# Remove Empty Second Line From Very Large CSV File in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, csv, database, postgresql

I have an very large CSV file (data for all the taxi trips in NYC during March).  The second line is empty which angers PostgreSQL's import.  I can run

```
(gc file.csv) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content file_trimmed.csv
```

to get rid of the offending line, but since it checks every line it takes a very longtime to run (the file is on an external drive and my computer is a potato).

Anyway to make this faster?

Comment: inplace is fine.

Comment: `$x=gc file.csv; $x[0,2+3..($x.Count-1)] | set-content file_trimmed.csv` i.e. removing just the second line (index 1) _could_ be faster. Unfortunately, I can't `measure-command` not having sufficiently large file:)

Comment: I can help you with that :) https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2016-03.csv  Let me test your recommendation.

Comment: @JosefZ Interestingly, it didn't seem to work on a much smaller file I ran as a test.   https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2014-03.csv  The 2nd line wasn't removed.

Comment: Is PostgreSQL OK with there being extra spaces before/after the column names in the first row? If so, it'd be pretty easy to adjust a few bytes in place without needing to read in the whole file.

Comment: @BenN I'm not sure but I'm happy to test.

Comment: There is `0x0A0A0D0A` i.e. LF,LF,CR,LF i.e. **two empty lines** between header line and first data line… Use `$x[0,3+4..($x.Count-1)]`

Comment: play with the `readcount` parameter of `gc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
gc file.csv | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content file_trimmed.csv
```

What's wrong in the original command (paraphrased [Delete all blank lines from a text file using PowerShell](http://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/08/delete-all-blank-lines-from-text-file.html) in *Tim Curwick's PowerShell blog*):

> The parentheses around the `Get-Content` statement force it to finish
>   loading the **whole contents** into an object before sending them down
>   the pipeline. (If we are writing to a different file than we were
>   reading from, we could speed up the command by eliminating the
>   parentheses, thus allowing us to read from the one and write to the
>   other simultaneously.)

**Test script** `1264263.ps1` measures merely *reading* [a large file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2014-03.csv) and omits writing to an output one:

```
param (
        [Parameter()][string]$file = 'green_tripdata_2014-03.csv'
)

Push-Location 'D:\test'

#$file = 'green_tripdata_2014-03.csv'
"$file`: {0:N3} KiB" -f $((Get-Item $file).Length /1024 )

' GC $file                          :' + ' {0:N7} sec' -f (Measure-Command {
    $y = Get-Content $file
}).TotalSeconds

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
' GC $file  | ? {$_.trim()}         :' + ' {0:N7} sec' -f (Measure-Command {
    $y = (Get-Content $file | 
        Where-Object {$_.trim()}) #| Set-Content "$file2"
}).TotalSeconds

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
' GC $file  | ? {$_.trim() -ne ""}  :' + ' {0:N7} sec' -f (Measure-Command {
    $y = (Get-Content $file | 
        Where-Object {$_.trim() -ne "" }) #| Set-Content "$file2"
}).TotalSeconds

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
'(GC $file) | ? {$_.trim() -ne ""}  :' + ' {0:N7} sec' -f (Measure-Command {
    $y = (Get-Content $file) | 
        Where-Object {$_.trim() -ne ""} #| Set-Content "$file2"
}).TotalSeconds

Pop-Location
```

**Output** shows that improved command (case #3) could work cca 10 times faster than the original one (case #4):

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SU\1264263.ps1
green_tripdata_2014-03.csv: 197,355.560 KiB
 GC $file                          : 27.4584778 sec
 GC $file  | ? {$_.trim()}         : 59.2003851 sec
 GC $file  | ? {$_.trim() -ne ""}  : 61.0429012 sec
(GC $file) | ? {$_.trim() -ne ""}  : 615.8580773 sec
PS D:\PShell>
```

Comment: Many thanks. On the larger yellow file, the elapsed time changed from longer than I had patience for to 10 minutes.